# ASP.NET MVC model binding not working with list of items

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Part of my view looks like

```
<table border="1" class="table table-hover">
                    <tr><th>Item</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Shirt</td>
                            <td>T-Shirt</td>
                            <td>5.0000</td>
                            <td><select class="form-control" id="items_1_" name="items[1]"><option value="">Select quantity</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Shirt</td>
                            <td>Full-Sleeve</td>
                            <td>6.0000</td>
                            <td><select class="form-control" id="items_2_" name="items[2]"><option value="">Select quantity</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Trousers</td>
                            <td>Half</td>
                            <td>4.0000</td>
                            <td><select class="form-control" id="items_3_" name="items[3]"><option value="">Select quantity</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Trousers</td>
                            <td>Full</td>
                            <td>6.0000</td>
                            <td><select class="form-control" id="items_4_" name="items[4]"><option value="">Select quantity</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select></td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
```

My controller looks like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RequestLaundry(int laundry, int pickuphour, int pickupminute, int[] items)
{
    var req = Request.Form;
    return View();
}
```

The data posted to controller from view looks like

> {laundry=1&pickuphour=17&pickupminute=16&items%5b1%5d=5&items%5b2%5d=0&items%5b3%5d=1&items%5b4%5d=4}

Though all other model parameters are getting bound with default model binder, `items` is `null`. However, the post request looks fine to me. I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.0 with VS2015. Where could the problem be?

Comment: Share the Razor view of the posting form.

Comment: @Rusty The output of `Request.Form` is there towards the end of the post

Comment: @Holmes_Sherlock Is Items a list of string/ number or list of complex type? Share the model, it can help a lot.

Comment: I have posted the rendered view. `items` comes from `select` control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing items[0]
Array or list is zero based. Model binder is getting confused since it cant find the first item.
You can avoid using numbered indexer at all by using following syntax

```
name="items[]"
```

Comment: Alternatively, just don't index any of these, i.e. `name="items[]"`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: Or (because its a simple property type) just `name="items"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I didn't know that a simple property type can be consolidates as an array by default model binder. Tried and worked. Thanks.